# Useful shortcut to open Intellij project(maven or SBT) from command line

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea, sbt, iterm2

I have to create a terminal/iterm short cut to open and auto import the projects of maven or SBT etc...

Right now I have to open IntelliJ first and then import the project manually.

Is there any command line (i.e. either terminal or iterm2) short cut for this ? I am using Mac.

Comment: pls  care to accept if you are okay with answer. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I hope your intellij is copied in applications folder of mac os 
if so below command will work well

```
alias int='open -a  "IntelliJ IDEA CE"'
```

Basically you can create an alias for this and keep it in your .bashrc
Your maven or sbt projects will be auto imported if you go to the project folder where pom.xml or sbt build file exists and 
then you can say

```
 int .
```

This will invoke(open)/auto import your project in Intellij IDE.

This works well for mac terminal or iterm